# About the paper from Marcinkiewicz, Jessen ad Zygmund

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am studying the paper from Marcinkiewicz, Jessen ad Zygmund on differentiability of multiple integrals. At page 221 he writes
\begin{equation*}
f(P)=\phi(P)+\psi(P)
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
\int_S|\psi(P)dP<\epsilon.
\end{equation*}
I guess this is possibile by density of continuous functions in $L^1$. Just below this, there is another equation that is
\begin{equation*}
\int_S|\psi(P)\log^+|\lambda\psi(P)|dP+\frac{B}{\lambda}<\epsilon.
\end{equation*}
I really don't get how is it possible to come to this inequality...since $\lambda$ is chosen large enough to have $\frac{B}{\lambda}<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$, how can i bound a priori the integral also by $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$?.

Comment: It seems it's this paper: https://eudml.org/doc/212787

Comment: I changed tags from "calculus" to "real-analysis" & "functional-analysis" & "harmonic-analysis". I'm not sure which of these three (or perhaps another tag) best fits your specific question, but the three I've chosen certainly apply to *Note on the differentiability of multiple integrals* by Jessen/Marcinkiewicz/Zygmund (1935), and "calculus" (as generally understood in MSE) is definitely not a good fit for either your question or the paper.